# Vue - Spotify API Auth. Login problems

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, spotify

I would like to create an app with Vue SPA (webpack) and the Spotify API. Unfortunately I can't get the Authentication right. So there is a basic code snippet from Spotify Which you can use to build your app. I tried to use that code and rewrite it so I can use it with Vue. That didn't work out quite nice and I have all kinds of problems. I've registered my App, and saved my details such as client id etc.

The original snippet from Spotify

http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/62wafrm7/

Problems

- Code doesn't log the response from the call. The pop up from spotify auth/login gives me a auth token in the url but doesn't close either. Also the display property stays false so it seems there is going something wrong at the login/auth function.

Code:

```
<button class="button is-spotify" :class="{display : display}" @click="getAuth()">Login to Spotify <i class="fa fa-spotify"></i></button>
```

Methods

```
methods: {

        login(callback) {

            var CLIENT_ID = '3f6be5c8306741c8ab06713da0a92f59';
            var REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/#/account';

            function getLoginURL(scopes) {
                return 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID +
                  '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI) +
                  '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' ')) +
                  '&response_type=token';
            }

            var url = getLoginURL([
                'user-read-email'
            ]);

          var width = 450,
              height = 730,
              left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
              top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);

          window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
              var hash = JSON.parse(event.data);
              if (hash.type == 'access_token') {
                  callback(hash.access_token);
              }
          }, false);

          var w = window.open(url, 'Spotify', 'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

    },

    getUserData(accessToken) {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
            headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        })
    },

    getAuth() {

            this.login(function(accessToken) {
            this.getUserData(accessToken)
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.display = true;
                });
            });
    }

    } // end of methods
```

So when I copy the token from the url, and paste that in as a data property and run the getUserData seperately it does return me the data, like so:

```
<button class="button is-spotify" :class="{display : display}" @click="getUserData()">Login to Spotify <i class="fa fa-spotify"></i></button>
```

getUserData function

```
getUserData() {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
        headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
}
```

But that's actually not what I want because than I have to set each hour a new token instead of users who just re authenticate each hour. So, I would like the same result as the basic snippet.

```
getAuth() {

    //run login + getUserData
    //maybe something like: get token and set it to this.accessToken


}
```

Comment: I've noticed your jsfiddle uses `$.ajax`, it does not follow promise specification. You would use `.done` and `.fail` with $ as far as i remember.

Comment: Hi, that's not te problem, `axios` works just fine with a simple then. Besides that, that's not the problem because I get response when I run the getUserData() function by it self as I describe above. So the problem is that there is something wrong with the authentication login.. I don't know what.

Comment: One problem I see is that the callbacks in your `getAuth` function have a different scope, so `this.getUserData()` and `this.display` will both be undefined unless you either add `.bind(this)` to your function declaration, or simply use arrow functions instead.

Comment: did you ever get this working? I'm struggling too